# Is there native OEmbed support (or a plugin that adds support)?

Tags: plugin

Is there a plugin available that adds support for oembed http://oembed.com/ to expression engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick check on devot:ee turns up [Media Embed](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/media-embed) for EE2. There's also [CE Tweet](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/tags/oembed) which claims to support it. Both are third-party plugins.